# SlickGrid column header out of sync with body

Tags: slickgrid, tableheader

What is the right way to keep column header in sync with body

I have tried (http://jsfiddle.net/wLPLA/4/) and got:

if number of columns is equal to `150` 
     the cells of header row rendered wrong  -- distorted at the end of row

If number of columns is equal to `200` 
     the header row got wrapped

What is wrong? Has anybody got the same problem? Any fix?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem is because of this line in slick.grid.js:212

try changing the width from 10000px to 20000px. I have a [working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/santoash/wLPLA/25/).

Comment: What variable was it that you guys changed from 10,000px to 20,000px? They've changed the source code on Slick Grid and now there are a few places around that line that use that value in the branch I'm working with. Frozen Column/Header + Grouped Header Column changes is what I'm working with. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!